# How to use a gesture API for Java series 40?

Tags: java-me, nokia, series-40

I was developing a Java application using NetBeans and Java s40 SDK. Here I need to use the gesture API for my application.

What would some example or sample programs other than racer program be? So it will be helpful for me to design the application. I also read the Nokia gesture API notes, but I didn't understand clearly. If possible, what is the link which shows an example with code and notes?

Answer (score 0):

Check *[Java - code examples](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Code_examples/)* for Nokia Series 40. The Paint example is a simple one.